# Problem with CORS Policy in dotNET with Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angular, cors

I have done a little Back-End project in dotNET 6, and now I'm starting a new Angular project. I have done all the settings, but it seems I'm missing something.
Let's start saying this is the **launchSettings.json** in the dotNET project:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:38144",
      "sslPort": 44337
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "BackEnd_BlogDemo": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7184;http://localhost:5146",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the Front-End, I have the **environment** folder, which inside there are: **environment.prod.ts** and **environment.ts** .
Call from FrontEnd to BackEnd only works if I put the ApiURL: **https://localhost:7184** , but doesn't work if I call without the htt**S** , at the address: **http://localhost:5146**, it keeps telling meabout being blocked by CORS. Why that? this is my Policy configuration on the BackEnd side, in the program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy(name: "MyPolicy",
policy => 
{  
    policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
}));
```

And then:

```
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("MyPolicy");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

This is the CORS Policy error I get:

[image]

Just for the info, this is the authservice in Angular:

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  type: string = 'api/Auth';

 register(registerDTO: RegisterDTO): Observable<ServiceResponse<boolean>> {
    return this.http.post<ServiceResponse<boolean>>(environment.APIEndpoint + this.type + '/Register', registerDTO);
  }
}
```

And this is the environment.ts folder (the environment.prod.ts it's the same but just it's on production = false):

```
export const environment = {
production: true,
APIEndpoint: "http://localhost:5146/"
};
```

Comment: You could try sending header while posting your request like this `headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }`

Comment: Hi @ShadyRaso try to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in your request.

Comment: In addition, you can place `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` middlware before `app.UseCors("MyPolicy");`

Answer (score 0):

try adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to your api in your controller. for example:

```
 [HttpGet()]
 public string Auth()
        {
            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
    });
});



app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
```

**If you edit your code in this way, I think you will not have any errors.**